# Returning a list in GTM's Custom Javascript Variable

Tags: google-tag-manager

In Google Tag Manager, I am trying to return list that would look something like this using a Custom Javascript Variable.

[image: list output]

In my tag, I am pulling this Custom JS Variable like this:

[image: JS Variable in Tag]

The Custom JS Variable is looking for the value in a hidden input field and putting that value into this list. The Custom JS Variable looks like this:

```
function() {
  var el = {{st-find-closest}}({{Click Element}}, '#st-signup-list');
  var listElements = '{"' + el.value + '" : 1,}';
  return listElements;
}
```

This Custom JS Variable needs to do a loop through two comma separated items, such as "listname1" and "listname2".

It would be this return output that needs to go into the tag "lists". When I preview my tag how it is written now, this list variable looks like this:

[image: GTM Tag list display]

What I need it to look like is:

[image: GTM Tag requested list display]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function() {
  var el = {{st-find-closest}}({{Click Element}}, '#st-signup-list');
  var listObj = {}
  listObj[el.value] = 1;
  return listObj;
}
```

If you want it return a javascript object rather than object string.

Here is the code. In your preview, that looks like a object being stringify.

Comment: You are awesome! This helped to solve not only the issue mentioned above, but another issue I was running into. Thank you!